# How to check if user input exists in database in a Blazor Server app?

Tags: sql-server, blazor

I'm creating a Blazor Server project with login and I want to check if the email and password that the user introduces exists in the database(I'm using Sql Server). I created my method that is searching in the database in a class named BatranService and my login form in a Razor component, but I'm not sure how the code to connect these two would look like. I would appreciate any help, thanks!

```cs
     public class BatranService : IBatranService
    {
        private readonly VoluntariatDBContext _context;

        public BatranService(VoluntariatDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<Batran> GetBatranByEmailAndParola(string email, string parola)
        {
            Batran batran = await _context.Batrans.Where(c=>c.Parola==parola).FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Email == email);
            return batran;


        }
    }

    <EditForm Model="@batran" OnValidSubmit="@authBatran">
    <div class="container px-4 py-5 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card0">
            <div class="d-flex flex-lg-row flex-column-reverse">
                <div class="card card1">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center my-auto">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-10 my-5">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center px-3 mb-3"> <img id="logo" src="css/autentificareLogo.png"> </div>
                            <h3 class="mb-5 text-center heading">Autentificare</h3>

                            <div class="form-group"> <label class="form-control-label text-muted">Email</label> <input type="text" id="email" @bind-value="@batran.Email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control"> </div>
                            <div class="form-group"> <label class="form-control-label text-muted">Parola</label> <input type="password" id="parola" @bind-value="@batran.Parola" name="parola" placeholder="Parola" class="form-control"> </div>
                            <div class="row justify-content-center my-3 px-3"> <button @onclick="authBatran" class="btn-block btn-color">Intra in cont</button> </div>
                            <div class="row justify-content-center my-2"> <a href="#"><small class="text-muted">Ai uitat parola?</small></a> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom text-center mb-5">
                        <p href="#" class="sm-text mx-auto mb-3">Nu ai un cont?<button @onclick="deschideInregistrare" class="btn btn-white ml-2">Inregistreaza-te acum!</button></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 row" style="text-align:left; font-weight:bold">
                        <span class="col-12"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card card2">
                    <div class="my-auto mx-md-5 px-md-5 right">
                        <h4 class="text-white">We are more than just a company</h4> <small class="text-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</EditForm>

@code{

    private void authBatran()
        {

        }



}
```

Comment: First thing wrong: storing plain-text passwords. Use salt-and-hash instead

Comment: The safe and easy way is to use the provided template with "Individual accounts".

Comment: NEVER implement your own SECURITY!!!!!!!!!!!!! That end BADLY always... Try to use some existing solutions. There are IdentityServer, or Azure AD, Azure B2C or 3rd party social Auth like Facebook, Google, etc..